# Managing IPv6 rDNS

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, ipv6, reverse-dns

Still very new to IPv6 and I talked to my datacenter and they do not do rDNS for IPv6.

> Unfortunately we currently do not support rDNS for IPv6 allocations.
>   We can however delegate the IP block to a nameserver of your choice
>   for your convenience.
>
> If you have a nameserver you would prefer using, kindly provide us
>   with that information.

Does this mean I need to setup a BIND/NAMED server and control the rDNS records that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information they need from you is the name(s) of your DNS server(s). You can chose to set up your own authoritative DNS servers for that purpose, or you can chose to use one of the many providers of authoritative DNS servers. Some of them are free some are not, some supports RDNS for IPv6 some do not.

Since the information you need to give the provider is a hostname, you are free to update the A and AAAA records for that hostname as you see fit, so you can move between providers without involving your current provider again.

For example you can tell your current provider that your RDNS is hosted on `rdns1.example.com` and `rdns2.example.net`. Then you can set up A and AAAA records as follows:

```
rdns1.example.com A 192.0.2.1
rdns1.example.com AAAA 2001:db8:1::1
rnds2.example.net A 203.0.113.1
rdns2.example.net AAAA 2001:db8:2::1
```

Should you move to another provider you simply update the A and AAAA records to point to another provider. You can even use two providers simultaneously for redundancy (but replicating the records between them may be tricky.)

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes. Their message means they are willing to have you set up a BIND server to control rDNS records yourself for the IPv6 block you have been allocated.